# How to get rid of a white border around a bar

Tags: html, css

Im trying to make a site and it needs to have a progress bar in it. But whenever I try to make it, it just makes a white border around the bar for no reason. I dont really know how to fix it.

```css
hr.someClass {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 200px;
  height: 12px;
}
```

```html
 <hr class="someClass">
```

I don't really know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your bar

```
border: none;
```

Your have not specified what to do with the border, so html will set the default border.

also I would prefer making a progress bar like this

```css
.bar {
width: 250px;
height: 20px;
background: #f1f1f1;
}

.percent {
height: 100%;
width: 25%;
background: #4c4c4c;
display: block;
transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.percent:hover {
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">

<span class="percent"></span>

</div>
```

Comment: `border: none;` is the default setting. Unless he has specified a border, a border will not exist in the first place.